# don't want to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

In my UITableViewCells I need to download different image for each cell, what should I do for such kind of problem...

Comment: from where u want to load images??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use that method still, and then configure each cell independently. Just make sure your cell setup isn't on your construction block

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeue..];
if (!cell) {
    cell = ...;
}

cell.image = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

item will be  your dictionary of images

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"mainTitleKey"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"secondaryTitleKey"];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[item objectForKey:@"imageKey"] ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;
return cell;
  }
```